# Since I've activated the 'Strict Mode for Redirect URI', my Facebook Login is not working anymore

Tags: firebase, facebook-login

I have a chrome extension using Firebase that is running for years now.

Recently I have activated the **'Strict Mode for Redirect URI'** in the Facebook Login option, and the Login is not working anymore.

I've copied the URI givent by Firebase in the **'Valid OAuth Redirect URIs'** : https://safestkeys.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

But this link doesn't pass the **'Redirect URI Validator'** provided by Facebook...

When I try to log I get the following error messages:

1. *Blocked URL: Redirection failed because the redirected URI is not trusted in 
   the application's OAuth Client settings. Make sure that the OAuth Client and Web ID are enabled and add the domains for all your applications to the list of allowed URIs.*
2. *Unable to load this URL: The domain of this URL is not registered in those of the application. To import this URL, add all the domains and subdomains of your application to the Domains field of the application settings.*

I've also realized that even with these errors, the login actually works...